# AppEngine - Send files to the blobstore using HTTP

Tags: google-app-engine, http, blobstore

I'm trying to send files to the blobstore using http requests.

First I made a button to call the createUploadUrl to get the upload url.

Then I made a client:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL_FROM_CREATEUPLOADURL);

httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity("value1"));
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

But I have 2 problems:

- In dev mode: When I run the client it responses "Must call one of set*BlobStorage() first."
- If I upload the app: The url changes every time I call it, so when I run the client it responses "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

apparently the entity must be a MultiPartEntity.

This is the client code to get the URL:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(myDomain/mayServlet);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
Header[] headers = httpResponse.getHeaders(myHeader);
for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
Header header = headers[i];
if(header.getName().equals(myHeader))
uploadUrl = header.getValue();
```

This is the server code to return the URL:

```
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
String uploadUrl = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl(requestHandlerServlet);
resp.addHeader("uploadUrl", uploadUrl);
```

This is the client upload code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uploadUrl);
MultipartEntity httpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
ContentBody contentBody = new FileBody(new File("filePath/fileName"));
httpEntity.addPart("fileKey", contentBody);
httpPost.setEntity(httpEntity);
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

so easy... :(

Comment: It's pretty clear that this API was meant for standard browser form uploading, huh? They neither make it easy nor efficient to upload. It always requires two requests. Passing the data through server code and posting it might be possible, but loses the simplicity of using their receiver code.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you're trying to hard-code a single upload URL. You can't do that - you need to generate a new one for each file you want to upload.

You also need to make sure that you upload the file as a multipart message rather than using formencoding or a raw body. I'm not familiar with the Java APIs, but it looks like you're setting the raw body of the request.

Comment: Java APIs and overview: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html

Comment: Hi Nick, you are right, I wanted to use a single URL, How should I get a new one dinamically? Calling a servlet and returning it in the response? There is a better way?

Comment: Assuming this is client code, yes: create a servlet that returns an upload URL when called, and use that to get a fresh URL for each file.

Comment: Hi nick, I'm getting the url dinamically, it works fine, thx. But when I send the request to that url it responses Java Heap Space and it doesn't reach the servlet indicated in the createUploadUrl. I configured the VM to -Xmx1024m or 1536 and did´t work neither, I supose this isn´t the problem. What else could be? Thx a lot!!!

Comment: @david I'm not sure what "responses the Java heap space" means, but if it means you're getting an exception because you're running out of memory, and this is on the dev_appserver, bear in mind that you shouldn't test in dev with really large files - they're buffered in memory, unlike in production.

Comment: @nick, I tried sending a simple string and it throwed the Java Heap Space Exception too. Then I uploaded the app and it responded HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error. I'm really stuck with this. Thx a lot for your time, I apreciate it a lot!

Comment: @nick, i'm sorry for waste your time, it is my fault, I was making tests sending wrong entities like StringEntity. I sent a file and it works great. However thx a lot for your help, it was very helpful